# Finding decimal values using Impala regexp_like

Tags: regex, impala, regexp-like

I'm trying to come up with a regex pattern that will work with regexp_like in Impala and which will match values that are decimals (up to ten numbers followed by a decimal followed by one or more numbers).

I have a pattern which is working in .NET (`"^-?\d{1,10}\.\d+$"`), but this isn't working in regexp_like.

I've tried something similar in Impala (`"^-?[0-9]{1,10}\.[0-9]+$"`), but it keeps returning true for integers. Why isn't it requiring the decimal to be there?

Some expected scenario results:

```
0 = False
0. = False
.5 = False
0.1 = True
123456 = False
-123456 = False
123456.2 = True
-123456.2 = True
Test = False
```

I'd like to make it even more complex and disallow numbers that start with multiple zeros, but I can't even get it to require the decimal point.

Comment: Try `"^-?[0-9]{1,10}\\.[0-9]+$"`

Comment: Backslash is usually a literal escape in strings so you need to escape your backslash so that it sends a backslash to the regex engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex still matches integers because the `\` before `d` in a string literal disappears and the `.` remains and matches any char in the string.

See the [Impala `REGEXP_LIKE` documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_like):

> Because the impala-shell interpreter uses the `\` character for
> escaping, use `\\` to represent the regular expression escape character
> in any regular expressions that you submit through impala-shell . You
> might prefer to use the equivalent character class names, such as
> `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d` which you would have to escape as `\\d`.

Thus, you can use

```php
"^-?[0-9]{1,10}\\.[0-9]+$"
"^-?\\d{1,10}\\.\\d+$"
"^-?[[:digit:]]{1,10}\\.[[:digit:]]+$"
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. That was driving me nuts. I was wondering why "\d" wasn't working either.